# Menu synchronization

Tags: 7, routes

I am building a site with main-menu at header and side-bar-menu. For each main-menu entry there will be some sub-menus. And same sub-menu will be displayed into side-bar-menu according to the portal we are in. Is it any way (or module) to synchronized main-menu->sub-menu and side-bar-menu so that in case we need to change menu, we can change it in one place and reflects in main-menu and side-bar-menu.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main menu can be 1 level deeps links to content. You just maintain these links as your top level content links as needed in the Menu configuration page.

For each main-menu item, make a new Menu where you actually set the link from your node edit pages.

Use [MenuBlock](http://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) and like the [Context](http://www.drupal.org/project/context) module (or just default the Block UI, eww) set each sidebar menublock to appear for the appropriate main-menu url path.

**-- OR TRY --**

You can try to make main-menu your site tree of all links, then use 1 menu-block set to 2-level deep starting point based on the url path.

I usually try to do the 2nd option .... then find its inflexible at some point and need a collection of menus and menu_blocks as I first described which from experience works better. Especially for cross-linked content (you may get the wrong menu block in the 2nd approach, for cross linked content as it shows the first menublock that menu_block finds the link within).

Answer (score 1):

You want the [Taxonomy menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) module to do this. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> Transforms your taxonomy vocabularies into menus with ease!
>
> **Features**:
>
> - Custom Menu per vocabulary
> - Uses the default taxonomy term path or custom paths
> - Integrate with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)
> - Integrate with [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto): use URL/path aliases
> - Does not interfere with other menu modules

Comment: Thank you. But can I use link path in taxonomy_menu instead of just taxonomy term link?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but you can integrate the 'path auto' module.

Comment: I mean can I create a link using taxonomy term which points to the actual node but not the link like '/term/1' which contains the list of items containing that term.

Comment: Ofcourse, thats what 'path auto' does. Just the same as using path auto on nodes so instead of 'node/123' you would get 'your_page' as the link.

Comment: Thank you Alex. I am still not clear. I know path-auto can do that. I want to link another page (the page created using panels or views) so that instead of displaying related nodes of that term it displays the actual panel/view node. Is it possible to do so in taxonomy_menu.

Comment: @cissharp It does sound like taxonomy menu might be able to help, but it's hard to say. Might be worth installing it and seeing if you can configure it for your needs